# Dysfunctional jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I cannot seem to get this date picker working at all. I know it must be something I am doing wrong, but I just can't seem to figure out what though. I commented out my css file thinking that maybe something was overriding the UI styles. But when I run this using firebug, it acts like no events are firing when I click either the text field or the icon.

Oh, and I should mention that my custom UI package contains ALL widgets. So, datepicker is part of that code.

Here is my test code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css" /-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "both",
            buttonText: "Date",
            buttonImage: "images/date_picker_icon.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="date_entered" id="datepicker" class="icon-right" size="10" maxlength="10" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didnt find any issue while testing in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/hallie/MgXjW/), except for the extra function closure in the .ready() handler. Are you sure that all necessary files & paths are configured properly?

Comment: Hallie's fiddle works for me too, despite the lack of styling.

Comment: Hmmm...that's weird. Maybe I need to try re-downloading the jquery custom UI files and see if, for some reason, that fixes it. These are the worst problems to fix. I like when it's something that I obviously have done wrong. Sorry to waste both of you guys time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I had mismatched versions of the jquery UI css versus the scripts. I downloaded a new bundle and it works fine now.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your issue..change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Hallie. Unfortunately, the filename I have is the correct name.

Comment: I know that it's loading the file, because the button text shows when I roll over the image. Also, if it wasn't working, the image wouldn't show either.

Comment: Very interesting! When I go to your jsfiddle page and add my local css and jquery js files...it fails just like it is doing here also.